# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in JobsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Having an issue here with jobs_controller.rb when I remove the Devise module from my job.rb model below:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base

# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
# :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable

    devise  :database_authenticatable,
            :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

# Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
attr_accessible :contact_email, :contact_phone, :description, :district, :due_date, :expiration_date, :job_title, :posting_date, :requirements, :salary, :submission_process

end
```

I then remove the Devise module, and arrive at the resulting model:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base

    # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
attr_accessible :contact_email, :contact_phone, :description, :district, :due_date,       :expiration_date, :job_title, :posting_date, :requirements, :salary, :submission_process

end
```

The thrown error when making this transition is displayed in the following trace:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in JobsController#create

SQLite3::ConstraintException: constraint failed: INSERT INTO "jobs" ("contact_email",     "contact_phone", "created_at", "current_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_ip", "description", "district", "due_date", "email", "encrypted_password", "expiration_date", "job_title", "last_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_ip", "posting_date", "remember_created_at", "requirements", "reset_password_sent_at", "reset_password_token", "salary", "sign_in_count", "submission_process", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:49:in `block in create'
app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:48:in `create'
```

I have a user model as well as a job model, the application consists of a basic scaffold allowing users to post and view jobs, contingent upon proper authentication with Devise. I'm relatively new to proper back-end construction, and have more experience with front-end, view type Rails stuff. Im not sure if I need Devise present in the Job model, or only in the User model.

Answer (score 0):

Generally Speaking, an exception like this means that you are violating a database constraint. Either a NOT NULL, UNIQUE or other kind of database enforcement on your table.

For instance, Devise enforces that fields such as email and encrypted password not be null.
You can look in `db/schema.rb` to see the constraints and indexes built for your tables.

In this situation, it is very likely that you are not populating the `encrypted_password` attribute and/or you are inserting a duplicate email. [You can remove these constraints with a migration if you need](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#changing-tables).

EDIT: In answer to your second question, you only need devise on the model with which your users authenticate (where their password will be stored). Then, to enforce that users can only create and edit jobs that belong to them, in your controller you say: `before_filter :authenticate_user!` and in your individual actions (or in another before_filter) you check that the Job they are trying to edit belongs to them.